# Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32' 400 error

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, null

I am trying to do POST request with some data is null. It is angular form.
Here is my payload

```html
DeviceDetail{
deviceId:'332',
sideId: null,
deviceName:'test'
}
```

But I got 400 bad request when I submit.
this is from response preview error.
0: "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'sideId'

Comment: That is because you must be trying to use sideId in your backEnd , check your backend .

Answer (score 1):

**C#:**

```
public class DeviceDetail {
   public string DeviceId;
   public int SideId; -> This will NOT allow null value
   public int? SideId; -> This will allow null value
   public string DeviceName;
}
```

So in your case, you have to force `null` value to `0`. For example:

**Angular:**

```
const sideId = sideId ? sideId : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Tartarus's your answer is right, but if you don't mind, I'll go further: from my opinion, handling this nullcheck like this inline method - just before sending the request - is not really elegant.

If 'sideId' can be null somehow, that means it is an optional parameter. In javascript, optional parameters and not defined variables are end's up in 'undefined' type, so something happening in the question giver's code. It would be nice to handle this problem right at creating the DeviceDetail object: so in your class's constructor, you can set a default value to this model, avoiding these "self generated NullPointerExceptions".

Also it's necessarry to check the backend's validation too. How is it possible, the validation not handles a required input data?